# Connect WP8 device to a bluetooth headset programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to connect a Windows Phone 8 phone with a generic bluetooth headset using some information stored on a NFC tag. As for bluetooth part, it should be possible to find paired devices, which are active, using

```
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
```

and call

> await socket.ConnectAsync(peer.HostName,
>   serviceName);

to connect to the particural device. However, I am unable to get the `serviceName`. According to documentation, the device should return advertised service in `PeerInformation.ServiceName`, but I am only getting blank string.

Is there some workaround for how to get nams of supported services (bluetooth profiles)? I specifically need to connect the bt device using A2DP profile, but I am unable to get (or even find on the internet) the correct service name string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectAsync` opens a socket for the calling program to send/receive data over. That's not what you want, instead you want the OS to connect to the Headset service. In Win32 that's `BluetoothSetServiceState` but I don't know an equivalent 'modern' API.

Also in Win32 one could use `BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx` which would cause pairing, *and* *probably* connect the headset services -- and with full Out-Of-Band authentication if supplied by the NFC channel. Again I don't know of an equivalent.

I suppose there's a possibility that doing a ConnectAsync to an arbitrary endpoint (e.g. `"15"`) will cause pairing to start which will then complete and enable the Headset service... The ConnectAsync call itself will fail but it is its side-effect we're interested in. May be worth a try.

Presumably you're getting the headset device's device address from the NFC comms? If so, you can create the `HostName` object to use in the `ConnectAsync` as Peter describes: http://peterfoot.net/PersistBluetoothAddressesOnWindowsPhone8.aspx

Comment: You are my savior. :) Using ConnectAsync to an arbitrary endpoint seems to be working. As for NFC: I can only use a passive token with some short information stored, so I was thinking about storing MAC address of the bluetooth device. Then I could discover paired devices and connect to the one with desired MAC address.

Comment: Good! Glad to help. You can (apparently) use the MAC Address without needing to do discovery... Answer edit #2.